# Angular - PrimeNG datatable date issue

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I want to display the date in each column of my datatable. The date is comming via json and looks like:

**JSON Date**

```
1504836960000
```

Now i am formatting it via piping and ng-template:

```
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-order="rowData">
   {{order.sla.slaEnd | date:'yMdjm'}}
</ng-template>
```

I am getting a date looking like this: `8.9.2017, 04:16`

**Whole column code**

```
<p-column field="sla.slaEnd" header="SLA">
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-order="rowData">
        {{order.sla.slaEnd | date:'yMdjm'}}
    </ng-template>
</p-column>
```

The problem is, when `sla.slaEnd == null` i am getting an error and my page collapses. 
I have tried a lot but i didn't get it to check if `sla.slaEnd != null`.
I want to check if it is null and when it is null he should display nothing like ''. When it is not null then just show my formatted date. Anybody knows how to solve this issue?

Comment: why not wrap it in `<ng-template *ngIf="sla.slaEnd != null"> //your <p> </p></ng-template>` ?

Comment: Doesn't work because sla is not a variable in my component.ts but an object of my datatable value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [safe navigation operator.](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#safe-navigation-operator)

`{{order.sla?.slaEnd}}`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `*ngIf=""`:

```
<p-column *ngIf="sla.slaEnd" field="sla.slaEnd" header="SLA">
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-order="rowData">
        {{order.sla.slaEnd | date:'yMdjm'}}
    </ng-template>
</p-column>
```

Comment: This is not what i want. If sla.slaEnd is null the whole column will not be displayed. But i want it always to be there.